# Python crashed, Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: python, tensorflow, crash

I'm trying to run tensorflow's [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/layers/cnn_mnist.py) from their github but at some point I'm getting window "python crashed" and stopped process in PyCharm:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Execution is interrupted at [143rd line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/layers/cnn_mnist.py#L143). I found several solutions but **none helped**:

1. To Environment variables in Run/Debug Configurations dialog add this pair: `=C:` as NAME and `c:\''` as VALUE
2. Uncheck PyQt compatible ckeckbox in PyCharm project Settings

Problem is still remain

Windows 7 x64, PyCharm 2018.2.4 (Community Edition), Python 3.6.5

**UPD:** script is finished correctly if I exclude all pooling layers from NN topology

**UPD2:** script works fine even with pooling layers if it run from anaconda prompt so problem is hidden in pycharm?

Comment: Sorry for the bump, but having the same issue. Not using pycharm solved it?

Comment: @eXistanCe in my case - see UPD and UPD2 - yes, somehow. PyCharm could still be used as convenient editor but to run project I used conda prompt